# Looking to read in hex values from txt file

Tags: arrays, hex

I'm trying to read in some hex values from a txt file in the format.

Plaintext=  a7f1d92a82c8d8fe
Othertext= 76f467db07371675

Plaintext=  434d98558ce2b347
Othertext= f1c67a7ee683eca2

These values are then to be fed into a calculation. I've tried using the code below but am having 2 issues. First I can only seem to feed it in as a string. Second I can for all that's good figure out how to define the array that will store them. I need something that will put them in something like:

char Plaintextarray [8][3] = { "a7","f1","d9","2a","82","c8","d8","fe" };

Thanks, Liam.

```
void ReadTextPairs()
{
string array[700]; // creates array to hold names
string Parray[700];
string Carray[700];
string line; //this will contain the data read from the file

short loop = 0; //short for loop for input
int i = 0, j = 0;

    ifstream myfile("C:\\textfile.txt"); //opening the file.

if (myfile.is_open()) //if the file is open
{
    while (!myfile.eof()) //while the end of file is NOT reached
    {
        getline(myfile, line); //get one line from the file
        if (line.find("Plaintext=") != string::npos) { Parray[i] = line.substr(12); i++; }
        if (line.find("Othertext=") != string::npos) { Carray[j] = line.substr(12); j++; }
        array[loop] = line;
        loop++;
    }
    myfile.close(); //closing the file


    for (int k = 0; k < (i - 1); k++) {
        cout << Parray[k] << "\t" << Carray[k] << "\n";
    }
}
else cout << "Unable to open file"; //if the file is not open output

printf("\nNumber of key pairs read %d\n", i);
//return ();
  }
```

Comment: After reading many times your question, I still don't understand what is your question. You say "I can only seem to feed it in as a string" but you don't explain what you would like to do instead. Then you say "I need something like: char Plaintextarray [8][3] = {...};" but why 8 and 3 ? Why 2 dimensions ? And what about Othertext ? In short, if you want a relevant answer, here is what you need to do: you need to provide a sample of the input file, then provide the output you're currently getting with this sample and provide the expected output that you want with this sample as input. Can you?

Comment: Ok I understand now the Plaintextarray [8][3] example, you want Plaintextarray [8][3] instead of what you currently have which is Parray[8] and Carray[3],  right? But still provide input / current output / desired output please

Comment: So my input is a text file containing a sequential list of information in the format:

Plaintext=  a7f1d92a82c8d8fe
Othertext= 76f467db07371675

Plaintext=  434d98558ce2b347
Othertext= f1c67a7ee683eca2

This list continues on for another 100 entries. The item I need to extract is the 'a7f1d92a82c8d8fe'. This is a 32bit hex key. 
I need to extract these keys into an array. The format that I have for a manual entry into an array for the Plaintext called Plaintextarray is in the format:
char Plaintextarray [8][3] = { "a7","f1","d9","2a","82","c8","d8","fe" };

Comment: How do I extract the keys from the text file into an array of the same format as the Plaintextarr